# wmi wql query of etw event source

Tags: wmi, event-log, etw, wql

How would I go about subscribing to a WMI event which notifies me of a new entry in the error log?  The error log in question would be generated as a result of a call to an ETW event source.

I've noticed the following WMI query:
SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent

I'm not sure if this would work or even if it is too wide a query for picking up entries in specific ETW based event logs.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: C# mainly. It doesn't really matter as long as I can work out how to do it.